# How to contact Microsoft regarding security flaw?

Tags: privacy, microsoft

[Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/msrc/faqs-report-an-issue) I see:

> If you believe you have found a security vulnerability that meets Microsoft's definition of a security vulnerability, please submit the report to MSRC at https://msrc.microsoft.com/create-report

Also [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/msrc/faqs-bounty):

> We want to know about a security vulnerability as soon as you’ve found it.

But..

When signing into the create-report page (via google auth or MS account), it signs in as expected but signs out ~5 seconds later (using Chrome, also in Chrome incognito, and safari on macOS Catalina).

After signing out, it redirects to https://msrc.microsoft.com/create-report:

[image]

I have called MS's tech support number (the call center did not come across as knowledgable about cyber security), and emailed `bounty@microsoft.com`, but have not received a reply.

How can one submit a bug report on a security vulnerability - is there a direct phone number for MS Cyber Security?

UPDATE

I received a reply

> Thank you for contacting the Microsoft Security Response Center (MSRC). Secure@microsoft.com is the proper e-mail address to report security vulnerabilities to.   In order to investigate your report I will need a valid proof of concept (POC) ideally with images or video, the detailed steps to reproduce the problem, and how an attacker could use it to exploit another user.  Please also note that all bounty/acknowledgement decisions are made at a point past when an issue is cased and cannot be addressed here.

And

> This thread is being closed and no longer monitored. When ready, submit a new report at . (sic)

I presume microsoft intended to include a link to the https://msrc.microsoft.com/create-report, although it's not clear as they appear to have made a typo.

In any case, it appears contacting `Secure@microsoft.com` is one method microsoft recommend.

Comment: They are apparantly using third-party cookies for authentication, which are getting blocked by all modern browsers. I can reproduce that in Chrome and Edge. You'll need to wait until they've fixed that. I think secure@microsoft.com should work to submit the issue.

Comment: @MartinFürholz wow - thanks for doing that - I thought I was going crazy. I am a noob at cyber security (maybe too many hollywood films), but I would have thought big tech like MS would want to know immediately about security flaws. It shocks me how slow they are to respond, the bounty@ email doesn't give a response, and especially since their call center doesn't know how to handle and their forms are broken.

Comment: Try secure@microsoft.com

Comment: @MartinFürholz thanks, I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://hackerone.com/bing

> If you have found a security vulnerability in any of Microsoft’s
> online services, please send e-mail to secure@microsoft.com. We will
> respond to your submission within 24 hours and start working right
> away to remediate the vulnerability. To help our engineers identify
> the potential vulnerability, please include as much information in
> your report as possible. For example, include the following:
>
> - Proof-of-concept and/or URL demonstrating the vulnerability
> - Type of issue (cross-site scripting, buffer overflow, SQL injection, etc.)
> - Any special configuration required to reproduce the issue
> - Impact of the issue, including how an attacker could exploit the issue
>
> To encrypt your message to our PGP key, please go to the [Microsoft
> Security Response Center PGP Key and S/MIME Certificate page](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/pgp.mspx) for
> further information.
>
> Please note that the Microsoft Security Response Center does not
> provide technical support for Microsoft products. If you need
> assistance with something other than reporting a possible security
> vulnerability, please see the statement below that most closely
> matches your situation and expand the statement for next steps.